# Flutter: flutter_downloader SQL not working properly

Tags: ios, sql, flutter, dart, download

I followed the setup instructions exactly to set up [flutter_downloader](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader).
I'm starting downloads from a method like so, which does show progress in the callback (exactly as in the docs):

```
  Future<String?> startDownload(String url) async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: url,
      savedDir: directory.path,
      showNotification: true, // Android only
      openFileFromNotification: false, // Android only
    );
    return taskId;
  }
```

Yet, calling the method as described in the docs:

```
List<DownloadTask>? tasks = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();
```

Often results in zero results, even though you have started a download prior.
This seems completely random.

I've also tried with a query with the same result, zero items. e.g.

```
List<DownloadTask>? tasks = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(
  query: "SELECT * FROM task",
);
```

**Anything I'm doing wrong?**